# What does "[Warning] Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address [scrubbed]." means?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, windows, vidalia, socks

What does "[Warning] Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address [scrubbed]." means? Vidalia occasionally gives this warning.

Comment: I'd like to know too. I got this message a few moments ago while trying to browse DrudgeReport.com. The browser was locking up .... and kept reloading every 30 seconds or so. Definitely not normal behavior for Drudge. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fixed for [bug #10419](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10419). Instead of a proper fix it "routes" localhost over Tor. See
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10419#comment:32

Comment: So does this mean that I can't use Tor browser to access a local webserver? If so, does adding 127.0.0.1 to the "no proxy for" box permit local access?